# Swift - adding a bottom line to UITextfield with spacing

Tags: ios, swift, autolayout, uikit, uitextfield

At the moment I am adding a bottom line to my `UITextfield` with this `extension`:

```
    enum LINE_POSITION {
    case LINE_POSITION_TOP
    case LINE_POSITION_BOTTOM
}

extension UIView {
    func addLine(position : LINE_POSITION, color: UIColor, width: Double) {
        let lineView = UIView()
        lineView.backgroundColor = color
        lineView.translatesAutoresizingMaskIntoConstraints = false // This is important!
        self.addSubview(lineView)

        let metrics = ["width" : NSNumber(value: width)]
        let views = ["lineView" : lineView]
        self.addConstraints(NSLayoutConstraint.constraints(withVisualFormat: "H:|[lineView]|", options:NSLayoutConstraint.FormatOptions(rawValue: 0), metrics:metrics, views:views))

        switch position {
        case .LINE_POSITION_TOP:
            self.addConstraints(NSLayoutConstraint.constraints(withVisualFormat: "V:|[lineView(width)]", options:NSLayoutConstraint.FormatOptions(rawValue: 0), metrics:metrics, views:views))
            break
        case .LINE_POSITION_BOTTOM:
            self.addConstraints(NSLayoutConstraint.constraints(withVisualFormat: "V:[lineView(width)]|", options:NSLayoutConstraint.FormatOptions(rawValue: 0), metrics:metrics, views:views))
            break
        }
    }
}
```

**My Textxfield:**

```
let emailTextfield: UITextField = {
    let v = UITextField()
    v.font = UIFont(name: "AvenirNext-Regular", size: 20)
    v.textColor = .white
    v.textAlignment = .left
    v.placeholder = "Email-Adresse"
    v.translatesAutoresizingMaskIntoConstraints = false
    v.addLine(position: .LINE_POSITION_BOTTOM, color: .blue, width: 2)
    v.addPadding(.left(60))
    return v
}()
```

My problem is that the line appears right below my text and I would like to have a bit more spacing in between text and line. Is  there a simple way to get this done?

Comment: did u try changing the vertical rawValue: 0 to rawValue: 10 ?

Comment: doesn't do anything

Answer (score 0):

Add to *metrics* array a new variable "bottomMargin" and set it's value. Positivities values will draw a line above the bottom side of a textView and negative values below. Next, update a visual format string to *V:[lineView(width)]-(bottomMargin)-|* for the LINE_POSITION_BOTTOM case

```
extension UIView {
    func addLine(position : LINE_POSITION, color: UIColor, width: Double) {
        let lineView = UIView()
        lineView.backgroundColor = color
        lineView.translatesAutoresizingMaskIntoConstraints = false // This is important!
        self.addSubview(lineView)

        let metrics = ["width" : NSNumber(value: width), "bottomMargin": NSNumber(value: -50)]
        let views = ["lineView" : lineView]
        self.addConstraints(NSLayoutConstraint.constraints(withVisualFormat: "H:|[lineView]|", options:NSLayoutConstraint.FormatOptions(rawValue: 0), metrics:metrics, views:views))

        switch position {
        case .LINE_POSITION_TOP:
            self.addConstraints(NSLayoutConstraint.constraints(withVisualFormat: "V:|[lineView(width)]", options:NSLayoutConstraint.FormatOptions(rawValue: 0), metrics:metrics, views:views))
            break
        case .LINE_POSITION_BOTTOM:
            self.addConstraints(NSLayoutConstraint.constraints(withVisualFormat: "V:[lineView(width)]-(bottomMargin)-|", options:NSLayoutConstraint.FormatOptions(rawValue: 0), metrics:metrics, views:views))
            break
        }
    }
}
```

---

**Result**

```
textField.addLine(position: .LINE_POSITION_BOTTOM, color: .blue, width: 2)
```

[image]

**Examining the View Hierarchy in case of problem**

Use Xcode Debug View Hierarchy Button [link](https://developer.apple.com/library/archive/documentation/ToolsLanguages/Conceptual/Xcode_Overview/ExaminingtheViewHierarchy.html)

Comment: I call it with those parameters: textField.addLine(position: .LINE_POSITION_BOTTOM, color: .blue, width: 2)